# ul tag not stretching properly and giving some weird margin errors

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm working on building myself a website, and I'm a bit stuck on the navigation.

[image]

As you can see, the li for the contact link is being forced down to the next line.

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mattheas Boelter</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" href="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" href="foundation.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="nav">
            <div class="container">

                <a href="#" class="left"><h3>TARDIS Maker</h3></a>


                <ul class="right">
                    <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #202020;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #101010;
}
#nav .container:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#nav ul li {
  float: none;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
#nav ul li a {
  color: #AAA;
}
#nav h3 {
  color: #AAA;
  margin: 0%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

The things that should be meantioned, are that I'm using sass for the css (because it's easier to write), and I'm using foundation.

To try to figure out the issue, I've opened up the inspector in firefox, and this is what I see when I select the ul:

[image]

So the ul is occupying that space.

Now, if I look at the li that is last on the first line, I see this:
[image]

So that li isn't occupying that space either.

Now, the thing is, that when I remove the margins on those li's, it works as expected (of coarse without the margins appearing)

[image]

Now, in foundation, the class `right` does add a `float: right;` style, so that could be the issue (I've found that if I add a width, it works a bit better, but I still get some similar margin errors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there's some issues with floats, margins and widths. You have things like `display: table;` and `float: none;` defined which you don't need. The text-align isn't needed either given the example, but isn't what's causing the problem.

The best thing to do would be to strip everything out. Look at [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwkg6t21/6/) I've created that uses the most basic of definitions to achieve the goal. You could also try removing properties and seeing what happens. You shouldn't need to define a fixed width on the container elements, apart from 100% on the header.

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
}

h3 {
    float: left;
}

.nav {
    float: right;
}

li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Above is the code from the JSFiddle which does the actual stuff, the extra stuff in the css in the example is just for demonstration purposes.

Setting 100% width on the header makes sure it goes the full width and has room for the child elements.

Floating the `<nav>` and the `<h3>` left and right respectively means they shrink to the size of their contents and don't expand and push other elements down.

Within the `<ul>` the `<li>`'s are floated left and a margin is applied. The `:last-child` selector takes the margin off the last one allowing the spacing to work. You could then pad the `<ul>` to space it evenly on each side.

Try the simplified example and see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you! Give me a few minutes to try this out on my site, then I'll be back to accept this if it works. This is looking the most promising to me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

float li to the left and use display:inline-block on the a's of the li. example:

```
.nav li {
float:left;
padding:10px 15px 0px 15px;
line-height: 20px; 
list-style-type: none;
 }

 .nav a {
 vertical-align: middle;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
line-height: 20px; 
padding:5px;
 }
```

Comment: Didn't make a difference, thank your for the fast answer though.

Comment: Maybe your width for nav area is to small then. try extending it a bit

Comment: You mean the container div? I set both that and #nav div to a width of 100% and it didn't make a difference. According to Firefox's inspector, they where already taking up the entire width of the screen and didn't have any margins on them.

Comment: add these. works for me on test site.                                                  .right{
width:30%;
position:absolute;          dont forget the periods before class name.
top:0px;
right:0px;
}

.container{
position:relative;
width:100%;
}

Comment: body {
  background-color: #202020;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #101010;
}
#nav .container:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#nav ul li {
  float: none;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
#nav ul li a {
  color: #AAA;
}
#nav h3 {
  color: #AAA;
  margin: 0%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.right{
width:30%;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
}

.container{
position:relative;
width:100%;
}

Comment: I decided to go with Toni's answer because it did the best job explaining what the issues could be. Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**css**

```
body {
  background-color: #202020;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #101010;
}
#nav .container:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#nav ul.right{
  width: 350px;
}
#nav ul li {
 float: none;
 display: inline;
 text-align: right;
 margin-right: 1%;
}
#nav ul li a {
 color: #AAA;
}
#nav h3 {
 color: #AAA;
 margin: 0%;
 margin-left: 10%;
}
```